# How can I lock Device not just the App but the whole device in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, lockscreen

I am working on a project which requires a device lock Button that enables users from the app to lock the entire device. Is there a way, package or any Platform plugin that I can use to implement that?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below plugin can help to lock phone in android.

https://pub.dev/packages/device_policy_manager

All details are provided on the plugin page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though we already figured it out by writing our plugin which uses Android Device Admin implementation. But we still don't have answer to iOS.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible on non jailbroken device, apple doesn't give any API for that.

I think that's because user have access to hardware button anytime.

Comment: how about **Android** ? any working solution please?